# "Unknown file type in" Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

`unknown file type in '/Users/m*****b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***Point-a*******/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSDK.framework/AWSDK' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I see this error when building upon having to change computers. The old computer builds the exact same app and version from Git, but I get this error instead on the new computer.

Any idea on what's going on or how to fix it?

Comment: Do a clean build or delete the DerivedData folder and try again.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it persists all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install git lfs then clone the repos again.